# Serialize many-to-many relationship in django rest framework

Tags: python-3.x, django, api, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to serialize database with the following relations:

1. Each Client can have one ore more Boxes
2. Each Box can contain one or more Products. Box and products have many-to-many relationship implementen through table BoxContent
3. Each Product has one ore more Questions related to it
4. Each Question has one or more Options

Take a look on ER diagram
[image]

So far I managed to obtain following results:

```json
  [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "tax_code": "client_1_tax_code",
    "email": "client_1_email",
    "box_set": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "edition_name": "first_edition"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "edition_name": "first_edition"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "tax_code": "client_2_tax_code",
    "email": "client_2_email",
    "box_set": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "edition_name": "first_edition"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

`box_set` is a collection of boxes that one particular client received. Ideally, I would like to have a collection of products and related questions under each item of `box_set`, like below:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "tax_code": "client_1_tax_code",
    "email": "client_1_email",
    "box_set": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "edition_name": "first_edition",
        "product_set": [
          {
            "product_id_1": {
              "id_company": "id_company",
              "sku": "product_sku",
              "question_set": [
                {
                  "question_id": 1,
                  "question_text": "Question about product",
                  "option_set": [
                    {
                      "option_id": 1,
                      "option_text": "Some text for option 1",
                      "option_type": "radio",
                      "image_url": null
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "question_id": 2,
                  "question_text": "Question 2 about product",
                  "option_set": [
                    {
                      "option_id": 1,
                      "option_text": "Some text for option 1",
                      "option_type": "radio",
                      "image_url": null
                    },
                    {
                      "option_id": 2,
                      "option_text": "Some text for option 2",
                      "option_type": "radio",
                      "image_url": null
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "edition_name": "first_edition",
        "product_set": [
          {
            "product_id_1": {
              "id_company": "id_company",
              "sku": "product_sku",
              "question_set": [
                {
                  "question_id": 1,
                  "question_text": "Question about product",
                  "option_set": [
                    {
                      "option_id": 1,
                      "option_text": "Some text for option 1",
                      "option_type": "radio",
                      "image_url": null
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "question_id": 2,
                  "question_text": "Question 2 about product",
                  "option_set": [
                    {
                      "option_id": 1,
                      "option_text": "Some text for option 1",
                      "option_type": "radio",
                      "image_url": null
                    },
                    {
                      "option_id": 2,
                      "option_text": "Some text for option 2",
                      "option_type": "radio",
                      "image_url": null
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "tax_code": "client_2_tax_code",
    "email": "client_2_email",
    "box_set": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "edition_name": "first_edition",
        "product_set": [
          {
            "product_id_1": {
              "id_company": "id_company",
              "sku": "product_sku",
              "question_set": [
                {
                  "question_id": 1,
                  "question_text": "Question about product",
                  "option_set": [
                    {
                      "option_id": 1,
                      "option_text": "Some text for option 1",
                      "option_type": "radio",
                      "image_url": null
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "question_id": 2,
                  "question_text": "Question 2 about product",
                  "option_set": [
                    {
                      "option_id": 1,
                      "option_text": "Some text for option 1",
                      "option_type": "radio",
                      "image_url": null
                    },
                    {
                      "option_id": 2,
                      "option_text": "Some text for option 2",
                      "option_type": "radio",
                      "image_url": null
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is my `serializers.py`

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Question, Option, ResearchCampaign
from nude_client_area.models import Product, Client, Box, BoxContent

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    company_id =serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["id", "name", "company_id"]

class OptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    option_type = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    answer_text = serializers.CharField(required=True, min_length=16)
    class Meta:
        model = Option
        fields = [
            "id",
            "id_question",
            "next_question_id",
            "answer_text",
            "option_type",
            "image_url",
        ]

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    options_set = OptionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    question_text = serializers.CharField(min_length=2, required=True)
    product_set = ProductSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    question_details = serializers.CharField(min_length=2, required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = [
            "id",
            "question_text",
            "question_details",
            "research_campaign",
            "options_set",
            "client_set",
            "product_set"
        ]
class BoxContentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BoxContent
        fields = ["id", 'product_id']

class BoxSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    box_content_set = BoxContentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Box
        fields = ["id", "edition_name", "box_content_set"]

class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    box_set = BoxSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ["id", "tax_code", "email", "box_set"]
        depth = 1
```

and my `models.py`. In my code I import `Client, Product, Box and BoxContent` form another Django app, but I put them all in one place just for demonstration purpose.

```py
class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=128)
    tax_code = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    is_partner = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    beauty_profile_filled = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='UNCOMPLETE')
    client_notes = models.TextField(null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name + " " + self.tax_code
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['email', 'tax_code'
        ]

class Box(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    edition_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class BoxContent(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    box = models.ForeignKey(Box, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Question(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(to='nude_client_area.Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    research_campaign = models.ForeignKey(ResearchCampaign, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    question_details = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=now, blank=False, null=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=now, blank=False, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class Option(models.Model):
    id_question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='options_set', on_delete=models.CASCADE) # TODO understand option_set name. It looks like confusing
    next_question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='questions_set', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    option_type = models.CharField(max_length=32, default="radio", blank=False, null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=now, blank=False, null=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=now, blank=False, null=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer_text
```

And my `api_views.py`

```py
class QuestionList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Client.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]    
    serializer_class = ClientSerializer
    filter_backends = (SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend)
    filterset_fields = ['id',] 
    logger.debug("My message")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I took advantage of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42775784/how-can-i-serialize-a-queryset-from-an-unrelated-model-as-a-nested-serializer?rq=1) with help of [SerializerMethodField()](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

`models.py` and `api_views.py` stayed pretty much the same. I just added custom `get_product_list()` method to my `BoxSerializer()`:

```py
class BoxSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_list = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Box
        fields = ["id", "edition_name", "product_list" ]
        depth = 1

    def get_product_list(self, obj):
        product_ids = obj.boxcontent_set.values('product_id').all()
        product_list = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
        product_questions = ProductSerializer(product_list, many=True).data
        return product_questions
```

basically, this method access `BoxContent` values and get only `product_id`s.
After that I fetch all products from `Product` table and pass it to `ProductSerializer` where I link with `QuestionSerializer`. For those who interested, take a look at complete `serializers.py`:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Question, Option, ResearchCampaign
from nude_client_area.models import Product, Client, Box, BoxContent

class OptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    option_type = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    answer_text = serializers.CharField(required=True, min_length=16)
    class Meta:
        model = Option
        fields = [
            "id",
            "id_question",
            "next_question",
            "answer_text",
            "option_type",
            "image_url",
        ]

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    question_text = serializers.CharField(min_length=2, required=True)
    question_details = serializers.CharField(min_length=2, required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = [
            "product_id",
            "id",
            "question_text",
            "question_details",
            "research_campaign_id",
            "option_set",
        ]
        depth = 1

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    option_set = OptionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    question_set = QuestionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["id", "name", "option_set", "question_set" ]
        depth = 1

class BoxSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_list = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Box
        fields = ["id", "edition_name", "product_list" ]
        depth = 1

    def get_product_list(self, obj):
        product_ids = obj.boxcontent_set.values('product_id').all()
        product_list = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
        product_questions = ProductSerializer(product_list, many=True).data
        return product_questions

class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    box_set = BoxSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ["id", "tax_code", "first_name", "email", "box_set",]
        depth = 1
```

In this way I was able to fetch specific products of each box the client has ever received.